# [emacs][Tuareg-mode] Symbol's function definition is void: dolist

Tags: emacs, ocaml, tuareg

I tried to install Tuareg-mode for Ocaml as advice on the Inria website.
Any time I try to launch it I have this error :

> Symbol's function definition is void: dolist

With edebug-defun

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-function dolist)
  apply(debug error (void-function dolist))
  edebug(error (void-function dolist))
  (dolist (buf (buffer-list)) (save-current-buffer (set-buffer buf) (if (derived-mode-p (quote tuareg-mode)) (progn (abbrev-mode (if val 1 -1))))))
  (lambda (var val) (set-default var val) (dolist (buf (buffer-list)) (save-current-buffer (set-buffer buf) (if (derived-mode-p (quote tuareg-mode)) (progn (abbrev-mode (if val 1 -$
  custom-initialize-reset(tuareg-use-abbrev-mode t)
  custom-declare-variable(tuareg-use-abbrev-mode t "*Non-nil means electrically indent lines starting with leading keywords.\nLeading keywords are such as `end', `done', `else' etc$
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "/nfs/ring/users/2013/phibonacci/.emacs.d/tuareg-mode/tuareg.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 13589
  load-with-code-conversion("/nfs/ring/users/2013/phibonacci/.emacs.d/tuareg-mode/tuareg.el" "/nfs/ring/users/2013/phibonacci/.emacs.d/tuareg-mode/tuareg.el" nil t)
  command-execute(tuareg-mode record)
  execute-extended-command(nil "tuareg-mode")
  call-interactively(execute-extended-command nil nil)
  recursive-edit()
  edebug--recursive-edit(before)
  edebug--display(nil 0 before)
  edebug-debugger(0 before nil)
  edebug-before(0)
  (edebug-after (edebug-before 0) 1 (autoload (quote tuareg-mode) "tuareg" "Major mode for editing Caml code" t))
  (lambda nil (edebug-after (edebug-before 0) 1 (autoload (quote tuareg-mode) "tuareg" "Major mode for editing Caml code" t)))()
  edebug-enter(edebug-anon0 nil (lambda nil (edebug-after (edebug-before 0) 1 (autoload (quote tuareg-mode) "tuareg" "Major mode for editing Caml code" t))))
  edebug-enter(edebug-anon0 nil (lambda nil (edebug-after (edebug-before 0) 1 (autoload (quote tuareg-mode) "tuareg" "Major mode for editing Caml code" t))))
  eval((edebug-enter (quote edebug-anon0) nil (function (lambda nil (edebug-after (edebug-before 0) 1 (autoload (quote tuareg-mode) "tuareg" "Major mode for editing Caml code" t)))$
  eval-expression((edebug-enter (quote edebug-anon0) nil (function (lambda nil (edebug-after (edebug-before 0) 1 (autoload (quote tuareg-mode) "tuareg" "Major mode for editing Caml$
  edebug-defun()
  call-interactively(edebug-defun record nil)
  command-execute(edebug-defun record)
  execute-extended-command(nil "edebug-defun")
  call-interactively(execute-extended-command nil nil)
```

"/nfs/ring/users/2013/phibonacci" is my home directory.

I followed this : http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TuaregMode (only replaced ~/.elisp/tuareg-mode by my own path ~/.emacs.d/tuareg-mode)

emacs 24.3.1 (2013) /
[tuareg 2.0.6 (2012)](https://forge.ocamlcore.org/frs/?group_id=43&release_id=662#tuareg-2-0-6-title-content)

Comment: Did you install the package from MELPA? I did just now and it works fine.

Comment: I have the exact same error. http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=QPMHZ0gJ

Comment: Alright, try to update to Emacs 24.3.4.

Comment: I don't have root access to this computer.

Comment: It's possible to build emacs from source without root, as long
as some basic stuff like gcc is installed.

Comment: Indeed but I'd like to make it work on my emacs version (which is used by 800 other computers). However I can't find the 24.3.4, the 24.3.1 is from March 2013 and is the last one I found on gnu.org. I could at least check if it's an emacs version issue.

Comment: https://forge.ocamlcore.org/frs/download.php/882/tuareg-2.0.6.tar.gz works for me

Comment: 1. State which Emacs version you are using. 2. Start from `emacs -Q` (no `~/.emacs` file), and show all the steps you followed. 3. Check from the beginning, and periodically after different steps, to see what the status of macro `dolist` is: it is predefined as part of Emacs, so it is no doubt present after `emacs -Q`. After you find out which step is problematic, and so which function, use `M-x debug-on-entry` to step through that function. IOW, narrow down the problem.  If the problem comes from your `.emacs` then bisect it recursively to narrow down.

Comment: Additionally to what @Drew said, try `C-h f dolist RET` in `emacs -Q`. It has been available in core since 2000-01-20!

Comment: I believe the problem isn't in `cl` package, but in expansion of some macro. @Phibonacci try compiling the file where you get the error by using `M-x byte-compile-file` and see where it breaks (if at all). It is also possible that it will not break and you will be able to use the byte-compiled version later. I predict some meta-quotation error there...

Answer (score 1):

`dolist` is from the common lisp Emacs library. If tuareg uses `dolist` without an `(eval-when-compile ...(require 'cl)...)` it's a bug.  As a workaround you can do `(require 'cl)` in your .emacs.  This is not recommended by the purist Emacs community, but it's fairly common.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC `dolist` was added to standard Elisp sometimes around Emacs-21, so there's something really wrong with your setup.

Comment: The function where OP gets this error is declared as an argument following `:set` keyword in the `custom` form. I'm 90% sure the problem isn't that the `dolist` isn't available, but that this form didn't expand properly and the interpreter is trying to `eval` the form w/o first processing the macros. This must be related to how different versions of Emacs treated `(lambda () ...)` form.

Comment: I don't see how this could happen: the backtrace shows Emacs is "eval"ing (aka interpreting) the `dolist` call, and in that case it definitely should expand the macro.